# Best way to make flutter app extensible by with external scripts/plugins

Tags: android, plugins, flutter

We are building android app with flutter (our first flutter app), and need ability to extend app functionality with external scripts or plugins. I consider to use javascript engine like https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore , but maybe there is a way to run external DART code in the app?

Mindaugas

Comment: Please add more information about what you try to accomplish. What is external **Dart** code and what is it supposed to do? Dart is compiled before it's deployed to the device, so there is not Dart code run in Flutter, only binary code (at least when released, debug mode on Android actually runs Dart code).

Comment: We are building player which connects to different content providers. So we want to make these connectors as plugins. Also depending on specific service some functionality in UI may be changed by this plugin e.g. for some services download button may be available but not for others. Plugins would be hosted on our website, and user installs only ones he needs.

Comment: It might be possible to do something like https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html, but I doubt Flutter has some direct support. You can probably create plugins (plugins in Flutter sense, native code for Android or iOS, needs to be built statically to the deployed apk) and then delegate the communication to such a service to this native Flutter plugin.

Comment: Faced the same issue tonight. After a bit of research, it seems like dart is the problem for now. But it may be soon possible. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/10530

Answer (score -1):

Just make a library of your external script/plugin and add it as dependency in your pubspec.yaml.

Comment: This way he needs to create (build, deploy) a different application version of every combination of plugins he wants to provide, or *always* include all plugins, but then they are not plugins (in the sense of the question) anymore.